# PHP? Given two strings, display only the text between the given strings

Tags: php, regex, dom

Trying to build a small dashboard for my ops crew to display the current NOTAM Runway Surface Conditions (RSC) for a given airport. Our operational needs can and do change dependent on the weather conditions, and the runway conditions.

Unfortunately the agency which publishes the RSC data, uses generic IDs, names, and classes for the DIVs for all the data on the page. So I'm left with ALL the data, even the stuff I don't want.

Here's the current script I have in which I pull the page with the data, and then hide all the elements I can:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("input.printcheckbox").remove();

    $("div#notam_station_whole_section").appendTo("div#NOTAMRSC");

    $("div#RAW").remove();
});
</script>

<?php

$str = file_get_contents("http://www.flightplanning.navcanada.ca/cgi-bin/Fore-    obs/ewx_traiter_notam.cgi?Recall=ni_File&Langue=anglais&TypeBrief=L&Rayon=50&Station=CYVR");

echo "<div id=\"RAW\">";

echo $str;

echo "</div>";

?>

<div id="NOTAMRSC"></div>
```

If you run the script for yourself, I'm left with a heap of text, and nearly all of it is irrelevant.

For this example, I'm trying to pull the RSC data for CYXX (Abbotsford Airport), in which the only information that is relevant is this text:

```
CYXX RSC 01/19 100 PCT DRY SN TRACE. 1312091630
CYXX RSC 07/25 100 PCT DRY SN TRACE. 1312091630
RMK: TWY ALPHA, DRY SNOW 100 PCT TRACE  ALPHA 1, DRY SNOW 100 PCT 
TRACE  BRAVO, DRY SNOW 100 PCT TRACE  CHARLIE, DRY SNOW 100 PCT 
TRACE  CHARLIE 1, DRY SNOW 100 PCT TRACE  CHARLIE 4, DRY SNOW 100 
PCT TRACE  DELTA, DRY SNOW 100 PCT TRACE  GOLF, DRY SNOW 100 PCT 
TRACE
RMK: APN APRON I, DRY SNOW 100 PCT TRACE APRON RUN-UP, DRY SNOW 100 
PCT TRACE
```

I've been trying to figure out a way to pull this ^^ text only in php, but since all the DIVs are the same, I can't seem to get any DOM or REGEX to work.

What I'm after is a script to display all the text between two given strings, and ignore the rest.

For this example, the first string would be:

```
000000 CYXX ABBOTSFORD
```

which ALWAYS precedes the RSC data I am looking for, for any airport (with the airport identifier, CYXX in this case, and the name, "ABBOTSFORD" in this case, changing).

What I'd then want is to display any of the text after that string, and before the next instance of:

```
</pre>
</span></div>
```

This would then allow me use this script for future airports as we expand, just by changing the first string to match the new airport.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Though you suggest "all the DIVs are the same". Is that really true? Do they not have any typical location within the DOM hierarchy that you can use to determine where the data you desire is located?

Comment: all the data I want is located in DIVs, all with the same ID and CLASS. eg: `<div id="notam_bulletin" class="notam_print_section">` , they then have a `checkbox` and a `span` which also have the same IDs as all the other relevant data. I was able to slightly modify what **Ed Cottrell** answered with, and am now able to present all the relevant data I am after. (until the web developer decides to change their website again, as unfortunately I've _yet_ to find a raw data feed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo preg_replace('#(?s)^.*?000000\s+CYXX\s+ABBOTSFORD(.+?)</pre>\s*</span>\s*</div>.*$#', '\1', $str);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/U2qtypraH36aNVfp)

Explanation: match anything and everything up to and through `000000 CYXX ABBOTSFORD`, then grab everything (in a non-greedy way) until you hit `</pre></span></div>` (with or without whitespace), and ignore everything else until the end.

Note that you can replace `CYXX` and `ABBOTSFORD` with whatever you want.

**EDIT** That should have had a `\1` above.

Comment: given this script:
`<?php

$str = file_get_contents("http://www.flightplanning.navcanada.ca/cgi-bin/Fore-obs/ewx_traiter_notam.cgi?Recall=ni_File&Langue=anglais&TypeBrief=L&Rayon=50&Station=CYVR");


echo preg_replace('#(?s)^.*?000000\s+CYXX\s+ABBOTSFORD(.+?)</pre>\s*</span>\s*</div>.*$#', '', $str);

?>`
I'm given no output.

Comment: What does that mean? Note that when I copy and paste your code, I get a lot of gibberish characters; I'm not sure what that's about.

Comment: Your update of `\1` seems to work!
Fantastic! Thank you so very much.

Comment: Honestly didn't expect to so slick. After seeing the potential here, I have a follow-up question if I may. If I alter the code to: `echo preg_replace('#(?s)^.*?CYXX\s+ABBOTSFORD(.+?)</pre>\s*</span>\s*</div>.*$#', '\1', $str);` - is there a way to repeat this and display all items with the CYXX ABBOTSFORD "heading"? currently it will just take the first instance and that's it. You've answered my initial request, so thank you, I'm just curious if we can take it one step further. Thanks again!

Comment: Look into `preg_match_all()`.  E.g., `$matches = preg_match_all('#(?s)\bCYXX\s+ABBOTSFORD(.+?)</pre>\s*</span>\s*</div>#', $str);` The output will be an array; do `var_dump($matches);` to see its contents.  You will want the items in `$matches[1]`.

Comment: Given your script, I get this:
**Warning:  preg_match_all() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given** the `var_dump($matches);` gives me **bool(false)** - as you can probably tell, I'm more than a little outside my comfort zone.
Based on looking up preg_match_all(), I see that most time `$matches` is defined as the 3rd parameter it's looking for.

Comment: `preg_match_all('#(?s)\bCYXX\s+ABBOTSFORD(.+?)</pre>\s*</span>\s*</div>#', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);`
 This provides me with an array output.

Comment: Oops, yeah, sorry - glad you figured it out!